# Xcode 4.2 stuck on My Mac64

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

Recently after I changed some project settings in my ios application project like the versioning and preprocessor macros, and also created a new configuration for testing. Whenever I run the app (simulator or device) xcode switch to 'My Mac64' and don't let me to switch back to ios. To get around it I have to go to the edit scheme page and switch between configurations to reenable the ios option.

I don't think that the changes I made to the project are related to this problem but I am not sure...

Comment: found it, I added 'agvtool next-version' the project run script build phase which caused the problem.